# Creating a new Queue in RabbitMQ with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, messagebroker

I'm having some issues creating a new queue in RabbitMQ.
I'm only creating a consumer client that will consume messages coming from another microservice.

Here is what I've done so far.

application.properties:

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=SCGLCCRAMQD0005.SCGER.DEV.CORP:5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=people-consumer
spring.rabbitmq.password=*************
spring.rabbitmq.vhost=PEOPLE

peopleevents.queue=qu-people-cores-update
peopleevents.exchange=ex-people-updates
peopleevents.routingkey=ONLINE.UPDATE.PERSONF.PERSONF
```

The config class:

```
@Configuration
public class MQConfig {


    @Value("${peopleevents.queue}")
    public String queue;

    @Value("${peopleevents.exchange}")
    public String exchange;

    @Value("${peopleevents.routingkey}")
    public String routingKey;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.addresses}")
    private String address;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.vhost}")
    private String vHost;


    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queue, true, false, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(exchange);
    }

    //@Bean
    //Exchange myExchange() {
     //   return ExchangeBuilder.topicExchange(exchange).durable(true).build();
    //}

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(queue)
                .to(exchange)
                .with(routingKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate template(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws IOException {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setAddresses(address);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(vHost);
        connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

}
```

And the listener class:

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQService {

        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMQService.class);

        @RabbitListener(queues = "${peopleevents.queue}")
        public void receivedMessage(@Payload Message message) {
            logger.info("User Details Received is.. " + message.toString());
        }
    }
```

When I run this, I have a ACCESS_REFUSED message but I don't know why.
Am I missing something??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RabbitAdmin` to create queues dynamically, so you need to add to your configuration class the `RabbitAdmin` bean:

```
@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
}
```

Then you can autowire `RabbitAdmin` with the `Binding` and `Queue` configurations:

```
@Autowired
private AmqpAdmin admin;

@Autowired
private Binding binding;

@Autowired
private Queue queue;
```

Finally you can create queues as you like:

```
admin.declareQueue(queue);
admin.declareBinding(binding);
```

You can create the queue in your configuration or service class.

You can implement it in your service class within a constructor:

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQService {

        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMQService.class);

        private AmqpAdmin admin;

        private Binding binding;

        private Queue queue;

        @Autowired
        public RabbitMQService (AmqpAdmin admin, Binding binding, Queue queue) {
                this.admin = admin;
                this.binding = binding;
                this.queue = queue;
                admin.declareQueue(queue);
                admin.declareBinding(binding);
        }


        @RabbitListener(queues = "${peopleevents.queue}")
        public void receivedMessage(@Payload Message message) {
            logger.info("User Details Received is.. " + message.toString());
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks, where should I autowired that? In which class? Im new in rabbit

Comment: You can autowire it in a service class, or in a configuration class.

Comment: I have edited the answer you can find an example.

Comment: Great! But now I get this error message: Error creating bean with name 'binding': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: Ok, I think to avoid all bean issues, I suggest to replace the queue creation to your service class inside a constuctor. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: Have you deleted the queue creation from your configuration class?

Comment: No, but after doing it, it requesting me that queue and biding method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245970/discussion-between-ismail-and-diegomg).